# SAPUI5 table binditems from expand performed in a bindelement

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying a proof of concept in SAPui5 to check the content of a searchfield, bind a result into another field, if i don't have any result i display an error message that has been written in a message field of my odata
so far i succeeded that this way

```
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: "/ExcSet('" + evt.getSource().getValue() + "')",
  model: "EXCEPTION",
  events: {
    dataReceived: function(response) {
      if (response.mParameters.data.Message !== '') {
        MessageBox.error(response.mParameters.data.Message);                            
      } 
    }
}
```

(If someone knows how to do that a better way, because using mParameters is not the best way, it is welcome)

Now, I want to extend my odata call with an expand navigation to display a table of results, by not using another odata call that the one i used already, so here is my code so far :

```
eanSearch: function(evt) {
    var oView = this.getView();
    var oTemplate = new ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        new Text({
            text: "{Volum}"
        }),
        new Text({
            text: "{Voleh}"
        })
        ]
    });
    this.getView().bindElement({
      path: "/ExcSet('" + evt.getSource().getValue() + "')",
      model: "EXCEPTION",
      parameters: {
        expand: "ExcMarmNav"
      },
      events: {
        dataReceived: function(response) {
        if (response.mParameters.data.Message !== '') {
          MessageBox.error(response.mParameters.data.Message);
        } 
        }
      }
    });
    oView.byId("table").bindItems({
      path : '/ExcMarmNav',
      template : oTemplate
    });
}
```

The data of the expand is loaded into my response as you can see here

```
    data: {
  "ExcSet('5410366897766')": {
  "__metadata": {
  "id": "http://...:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZEXCEPTION_SRV/ExcSet('5410366897766')",
  "uri": "http://...:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZEXCEPTION_SRV/ExcSet('5410366897766')",
  "type": "ZEXCEPTION_SRV.Exc"
  },
  "Matnr": "000000000040000000",
  "Ean": "5410366897766",
  "Message": "",
  "ExcMarmNav": {
    "__list": [
    "MarmSet(Matnr='40000000',Meinh='EA')"
    ]
  }
  },
  "MarmSet(Matnr='40000000',Meinh='EA')": {
  "__metadata": {
  "id": "http://...:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZEXCEPTION_SRV/MarmSet(Matnr='40000000',Meinh='EA')",
  "uri": "http://...:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZEXCEPTION_SRV/MarmSet(Matnr='40000000',Meinh='EA')",
  "type": "ZEXCEPTION_SRV.Marm"
  },
  "Matnr": "40000000",
  "Meinh": "EA",
  "Umrez": "1",
  "Umren": "1",
  "Eannr": "",
  "Ean11": "5410366897766",
  "Numtp": "HE",
  "Laeng": "20.000",
  "Breit": "20.000",
  "Hoehe": "10.000",
  "Meabm": "CM",
  "Volum": "4000.000",
  "Voleh": "CCM",
  "Brgew": "2.500",
  "Gewei": "KG",
  "Mesub": "",
  "Atinn": "0000000000",
  "Mesrt": "00",
  "Xfhdw": "",
  "Xbeww": "",
  "Kzwso": "",
  "Msehi": "",
  "BflmeMarm": "",
  "GtinVariant": "",
  "NestFtr": "0",
  "MaxStack": 0,
  "Capause": "0.000",
  "Ty2tq": ""
  }
}
```

But i don't know how to use resultset to bind it into a table, my code above is not working, if someone has an idea of the params to use for my binditems, or if there is another way to do it?

Best regards

Denis

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the binding of my table using an intermediate JSON Model based on the response of the Odata Model

```
eanSearch: function(evt) {
  var oView = this.getView();
  this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "/ExcSet('" + evt.getSource().getValue() + "')",
    model: "EXCEPTION",
    parameters: {
      expand: "ExcMarmNav"
    },
    events: {
        dataReceived: function(response) {
          if (response.mParameters.data.Message !== '') {
            MessageBox.error(response.mParameters.data.Message);
          } else {
            var model = new JSONModel({
            "items": response.mParameters.data.ExcMarmNav
            });             
            oView.setModel(model, "itemModel");
          }
      }
    }
});
```

And this is the XML view:

```
<Table id="table" items="{itemModel>/items}">
  <columns>
    <Column><Label/></Column>
    <Column><Label/></Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
      <Text text="{itemModel>Volum}"/>
      <Text text="{itemModel>Voleh}"/>
    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

works fine but I would like to avoid using the intermediate JSON Model and bind directly the array of the response in the table

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find what I needed :)

so the controller:

```
eanSearch: function(evt) {
  var oView = this.getView();
  this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "/ExcSet('" + evt.getSource().getValue() + "')",
    model: "EXCEPTION",
    parameters: {
      expand: "ExcMarmNav"
    },
    events: {
    dataReceived: function(response) {
      if (response.mParameters.data.Message !== '') {
        MessageBox.error(response.mParameters.data.Message);
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

}

and the view:

```
<Table noDataText="No Data" items="{EXCEPTION>ExcMarmNav}">
  <columns>
    <Column><Label/></Column>
    <Column><Label/></Column>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <cells>
        <Text text="{EXCEPTION>Volum}"/>
        <Text text="{EXCEPTION>Voleh}"/>
      </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
</Table>
```